# UIRefreshControl? does not have a member named 'endRefreshing'

Tags: swift, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to do a simple pull refresh with my UITableView, but is giving me the error: UIRefreshControl? does not have a member named 'endRefreshing'
I am getting a compile-time error at self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() in my onRefresh method
Here is the code for the viewController:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Rotten Tomatoes
//
//  Created by Dhruv Mangtani on 2/7/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 dhruv.mangtani. All rights reserved.

import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var moviesArray: NSArray?
var ratingsArray: NSArray?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "onRefresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl
}
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func onRefresh() {
    delay(2, closure: {
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    })
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    let RottenTomatoesURLString = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/top_rentals.json?apikey=rmvva9sq5s2tc2amv6db859f"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: RottenTomatoesURLString)!)
    if(isConnectedToNetwork()){
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response, data, error) in
        var errorValue: NSError? = nil
       let dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error:
            &errorValue) as NSDictionary
        self.moviesArray = dictionary["movies"] as? NSArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
    }
    else{
        println("NO WIFI")
        var networkLabel = UILabel()
        networkLabel.text = "No Network Connection"
        //self.addSubView
    }
}
    func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
}



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since UITableView's `refreshControl` property is an optional you must unwrap it before using it. You can unwrap with the `!` operator however a safer way is to use the `?` operator to unwrap, which will not result in a runtime error if refreshControl is ever nil.

So in your onRefresh method change...

```
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

to

```
self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
```

Comment: i did then and then it gives an error saying Cannot convert the expression's type '(IntegerLiteralConvertible, closure: () -> () -> $T3)' to type 'Void'

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. If you add anything above that line for example `let a = 1` or `println("test")` the error goes away. Weird.